# Java jar getResource not working in linux

Tags: java, linux, classloader, getresource

Same lines of code work in Windows but not in Linux. Code is run through a executable jar file.

- Entries in BuildPath: {PROJECT}/src,{PROJECT}/res
- Project Path of Test1.java: /src/com/qe/util/Test1
- Project Path of TC_Mapping.xml: /res/TC_Mapping.xml

.

```
package com.qe.util;
public class Test1{
    public static void parseTCMapping(){
    ...
        String xmlPath = TCDetailsExtractor.class.getClassLoader().getResource("TC_Mapping.xml").toString();
        System.out.println(xmlPath);
        InputStream is = TCDetailsExtractor.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(xmlPath);
    ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have resource in jar you should use `getResourceAsStream()` method to obtain its content. This might when files are not in jar but not when application is packed in jar.

Comment: I am already doing this at [TCDetailsExtractor.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(..)], the issue is this line of code works in Win but not in linux. InputStream is always set to null.